# Tell react hook that a "nested" object has updated, without copying the whole object?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

In my state I use a set to keep track of a selection. The set can grow to quite large size and as such I wish to prevent copying the set constantly.

I am using a hook for state as below, the code is working. However instead of returning a new set, I prefer to return the "old set", update the set in place.

When I do so, however, react doesn't notice the change and redraw events and other effects are not occurring.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<Set<number>>(new Set());

function onSelect(ev: SyntheticEvent<>, checked: boolean, event_id: number) {
    setSelected((selected) => {
        if (checked) {
            if (!selected.has(event_id)) {
                selected.add(event_id);
            }
        } else {
            if (selected.has(event_id)) {
                selected.delete(event_id);
            }
        }
        return new Set(selected);
    })
}
```

How do I tell react "hey I've updating xyz state variable"?

Comment: using `setSelected` is only correct way to update state, AFAIK. Also, I don't think difference in performance would be visible to user

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useCallback` like so

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
);
```

From the docs:  useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. `shouldComponentUpdate`).

Although you can use `useRef` like so

```
function useEffectOnce(cb) {

    const didRun = useRef(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!didRun.current) {
            cb();
            didRun.current = true
        }
    })
}
```

object ref does not notify react about changes to the current ref value.

Comment: I don't think the memoized callback is the answer, but I like the concept of using a ref to store the set, OP can use a separate piece of state (like an incremented counter) to trigger a rerender when the set is updated and always render `ref.current`.

Comment: The ref example wouldn't work, refs don't trigger renders.